# WCF invoke callback from static methods

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am very new to WCF and I am trying to learn but I think I am missing something significant here and I am aware of that so please be kind. I am working with a pre-existing console application that I have added a WCF host to, this is an oversimplified version of it but it should give you the jist of it

```
namespace mynamespace
{

    public class MyConsoleApp
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          CreateRemoteDebugHost();
          StartLongRunningMethods();
        }
        public static void StartLongRunningMethods()
        {
        LongRunningMethod1();
        LongRunningMethod2();
        }
        public static void LongRunningMethod1()
        {}
        public static void LongRunningMethod2()
        {}
        public void CreateRemoteDebugHost()
        {

            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(RemoteDebug), new Uri("net.pipe://localhost"));
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IRemoteDebug), new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None), "PipeRemoteDebug");

            //Create mex           
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            smb.HttpGetUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8001/RemoteDebug");
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            host.Open();
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(IRemoteDebugCallback))]
    public interface IRemoteDebug
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Message(string message);
    }

    public interface IRemoteDebugCallback
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void OnMessage(string callbackValue);
    }

    public class RemoteDebug : IRemoteDebug
    {

        public string Message(string message)
        {
            IRemoteDebugCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IRemoteDebugCallback>();               
            callback.OnMessage(message);
            return message;                
        }


    }

}
```

As you can probably tell I am trying to send debug or status messages back to a client(s) from inside of long running static methods. All the plumbing seems to be working correctly, the host comes up, I can add a service reference to my client application just fine but the trouble starts when try to invoke the WCF callback from the longrunningprocesses static methods. I can't seem to figure out how to do that properly.

What is also very confusing is that almost every example I have seen of WCF and callbacks assumes that everything you are doing is running from within the context of the WCF host itself, obviously in my example this is not the case. I know I'm probably going aobut this all wrong so could someone please set me straight on this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is client (not to be confused with the client program) created as well through app.config or manually (e.g. `public class MyClient: ClientBase<IRemoteDebug>` or `public class MyClient: DuplexClientBase<IRemoteDebug>, IRemoteDebug`).  This should send messages to the client programs. Example using DuplexClient above from some code I had:

```
[CallbackBehaviorAttribute(UseSynchronizationContext = true)]
public class SubCallback : IRemoteDebug 
{
      public void Event(SomeClass evt)
      {
         // some handling code using: 
         //public delegate void EventCallbackHandler(SomeClass evt);
      }
 }
InstanceContext ctx = new InstanceContext(new SubCallback ());


MyClient _client = new MyClient(
            ctx,
            new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None),
            new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/ServiceEndpointName"));
```

Also, you may want to pass some options to your service, such as:

```
    [ServiceBehavior(
        InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
        ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
    public class RemoteDebug : IRemoteDebug
    {}
```

It could be many things causing your particular issue, but this solved problems for me.

Comment: Thank you very much this totally led me down the right path. I appreciate it.